# Have two URLs Friendly in Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: opencart

Here is how mine works:
Say Product A is in Category X
My SEO URL (entered in admin) for Category X is "category x"
So when I go to that Category on the site I get www.domain name.com/category x...... all fine there.
My SEO URL (entered in admin)for Product A is "Product A"
So when I go to the Category on the site and drill down to the product I get www.domain name.com/category x/Product A.... all fine there too.

Now, when I find the product via search or via related products, the URL is different, as follows....
www.domain name.com/product A (notice that the Category part of the URL is now missing).

In other words, the URL for the product depends on how you navigate to find it, so my products have arguably two URLS each, at least. I imaging this could be confusing for SEO.

Or, does it matter. any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The product pages themselves have a canonical url, which by default is the link without the categories in it so it's not really a problem for your SEO. However you can use extensions [such as this](http://mos.so/5023) which will make all urls have the category link across the entire store

Comment: No problem in 2.0 version

Comment: ? Canonicals are available for both 1.5.X and 2.X